# Web push notification FCM will work on iPhone and iPad devices?

Tags: ios, web, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have one website and I have to send Web push notifications to all devices and all browsers. Base on my search I got some answer that Web push notification is not working on Ipad and iPhone devices. Right now I am using Firebase cloud messaging service for notification. here my code.

```
 firebase.initializeApp({
apiKey: "AIzaSy.....................KvPTQ",
authDomain: "dro.......firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://dsadasdasda-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "xyz",
storageBucket: "xyz.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "18........55",
appId: "1:183....6955:web:0a3.......5e",
measurementId: "G-L....31"
 });

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

So is it possible to do with APN certificate?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work to send push notifications (using Firebase Cloud Messaging) to browsers on iPhone devices as they don't support the Push API, https://caniuse.com/push-api. As far as other services than Firebase go I'm quite sure it won't work either. I did look around a lot for it myself but haven't found any solution so far unfortunately.

Even if you use a APN certificate I think you would have to take the route of making the user install a native app that handles the push notifications, which usually is what you are trying to stay away from when you decided to develop a web app. :)